# BlueJ: Cannot find symbol - method addMouseMotionListener

Tags: java, mouseevent, paint, mouselistener

I'm trying to make a drawing program that will draw circles onto a canvas using the mouseDragged() method from MouseMotionListener. Inside my init() method, I put in `this.addMouseMotionListener(this)` and got this error message:

Cannot find symbol - method addMouseMotionListener(Canvas).

I am trying to make it so that every time the mouse is dragged, the Brush (which is just a circle), will draw onto the DrawingBoard which has a Canvas on it

Here is the code for the DrawingBoard:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class DrawingBoard implements MouseMotionListener
{
    private Canvas myCanvas;
    private Brush myBrush;
    private PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    private Point p = a.getLocation();
    private int x = (int)p.getX();
    private int y = (int)p.getY();
    private Brush b1 = new Brush(x, y, 10, Color.red, myCanvas);
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own

public void init() {
    this.addMotionListener(this);
}

public DrawingBoard(int canvasSizeX, int canvasSizeY)
{

    myCanvas = new Canvas("Drawing Board", canvasSizeX, canvasSizeY);
    myCanvas.setVisible(true);
    myCanvas.setForegroundColor(Color.lightGray);

}


public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    b1.draw();
}
```

The code for the Canvas can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/RzMpkKhy

Answer (score 0):

Your DrawingBoard needs to extend some kind of AWT/Swing-Component like Frame, JFRame, Panel etc, that contains the method addMouseMotionListener(). Because your not doing this, the compiler assumes that addMouseMotionListener() is a method you defined somewhere in your class. But he can't find it (because it doesn't exist) so it throws an error. Try adding this method to the Canvas code:

```
public void addMouseMotionListener(MouseMotionListener ml){
  canvas.addMouseMotionListener(ml);
}
```

and put

```
myCanvas.addMouseMotionListener(this);
```

into your init() method.
Because the Canvas you are using is a custom class (there is another Canvas in the java.awt package), you have to alter its code to support user input (it doesn't look like it was designed to do this).

Comment: Would the parameter for the addMouseMotionListener be the constructor? Or should it encompass the constructor if I simply pass the entire DrawingBoard class as the parameter?

Comment: Because DrawingBoard is implementing MouseMotionListener, calling `myCanvas.addMouseMotionListener(DrawingBoard);` works. DrawingBoard qualifies as a MouseMotionListener by implementing it and overriding its methods. This works for every other interface as well.

Comment: Ok, so the cannot find symbol error is gone, but the canvas will not draw anything. Is it best to just have the DrawingBoard extend JPanel/JFrame?

Comment: You are not updating the x/y variables. you need to call `x=e.getX(); y=e.getY()` inside mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) and pass the results to your Brush object.

Comment: replace `b1.draw();` with `myCanvas.fillCircle(x,y,10);`

Comment: I have done all of this, but it still doesn't work. Extend JPanel/JFrame?

Comment: Extending JFrame would be the best solution, but the Canvas you are using can't be placed inside one. You would need to override paint(Graphics g) in JFrame to use java.awt.drawing methods.